Adding to Multidimensional Associative Array Fails in While Loop - Creates 2 Seperate Arrays (PHP/MySQL)
I am returning some mysql data and I want to add the results to a multidimensional associateive array, i try it in a while loop and it creates 2 arrays, if i do it manually it creates the array as expected, i have literally tried dozens of ways to get around this but for the life of me i cant see whats wrong.
Code:
<?php
//GO GET THE DATA
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

//SET THE ARRAY
$Array = [];
    
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // if i have data then output each row & add to the array
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                            

        $Array[] = [
            'name'  => $row["name"],
            'email' => $row["email"]
        ];
        print_r($Array);
    }
}

?>

The result is that I get 2 separate arrays instead of 1:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => John [email] => john@test.com ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Paul [email] => paul@test.com ) )

When I do it manually I get the expected output but not as part of the "while"
$arrTEST = [];
$arrTEST[] = ['name'  => 'John','email' => 'john@test.com'];
$arrTEST[] = ['name'  => 'Paul','email' => 'paul@test.com'];
print_r($arrTEST);

Result:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => John [email] => john@test.com ) 
        [1] => Array ( [name] => Paul [email] => paul@test.com ) 
      )

Can anyone point me in the right direction, pulling my hair out with this one.

You're running print_r() inside the loop, you're going to get output for each row.

put your print_r outside the loop. you don't have two arrays, you have one, and it looks like it was overwritten by the second code, which shouldn't happen , did you add the [] to this line after that error? $Array[] = [ because it works fine here https://3v4l.org/

Why not just select the two columns that you want, instead of SELECT *? Then you can just use $result->fetch_all() and it will return the multi-dimensional array that you're trying to create.

@AlexHowansky But the second output should have two row, the third output should have 3 rows, and so on.

@delboy1978uk If they weren't using [] there wouldn't be [0] => in each array, it would just be the associative array.

This would happen if you had $Array = []; inside the loop, instead of before the loop.

Yes @Barmar that's what I meant too, he must have changed it afterwards to $Array[] = [ because the code he shared works in the 3v4 link above i tried  it with

The print_r should be outside the loop
<?php
    //GO GET THE DATA
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
    //SET THE ARRAY
    $Array = [];
        
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // if i have data then output each row & add to the array
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                            
        $Array[] = [
            'name'  => $row["name"],
            'email' => $row["email"]
        ];
    }

print_r($Array);
?>

The output given should be correct, you might've assigned the new values to $Array instead of $Array[] and that's why its creating a simple array.
Make sure to assign it like this:
$Array[] = [
   'name'  => $row["name"],
   'email' => $row["email"]
];

And print after the loop

Having the print_r inside the loop wouldn't cause the output they show.

I know, but executing the same code they provided also doesnt give the same output they say. So the executed code might not be the same as the one provided

Then we should wait until we find out what the real problem is before answering.
